# Run powershell script, as administrator, via batch file with parameter passing

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, shell-script, powershell-5.0

When I run the script, without an administrator, via batch file it passes the parameter, but when I run the script, as an administrator, it does not pass the parameter.

I tried the command from the link, but without success:
[open-a-program-as-administrator-with-conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852226/open-a-program-as-administrator-with-conditions-e-g-h-or-something)

Command that executes the script, as an administrator, via batch file:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1' '%_vLUF%'  -Verb RunAs}"
```

The `%_vLUF%` is the parameter to be passed.

Error message:

```
No line:1 character:4
+ & {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolic ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Command in powershell script to receive the parameter:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF
)
```

What could be wrong, the command in the batch file or in the powershell script?

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer in the link below:
[run-powershell-script-as-administrator-via-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72563402/run-powershell-script-as-administrator-via-batch-file-with-parameter-passing)

This is how it worked:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1\" -_vLUF %_vLUF%'"
```